# How to use List<GameObject> insteal GameObject[] when instantiating and destroying objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class SliderManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider slider;
    public List<GameObject> InstantiatedObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    public GameObject Model;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        SetSlider((int)slider.value);
    }

    protected void SetSlider(int x)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < slider.value; i++)
        {
            bool mustBeAnObject = i < x;

            if ((mustBeAnObject) && (InstantiatedObjects[i] == null))
                InstantiatedObjects.Add(Instantiate(Model));
            else if ((!mustBeAnObject) && (InstantiatedObjects[i] != null))
            {
                if (!Application.isPlaying)
                {
                    InstantiatedObjects.RemoveAt(i);
                    DestroyImmediate(InstantiatedObjects[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    InstantiatedObjects.RemoveAt(i);
                    Destroy(InstantiatedObjects[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i used array before :

```
public GameObject[] Objects = new GameObject[100];
```

it was working fine i looped over the Objects array but then i had a problem to remove items from the array when destroying the objects so i tried to switch the array to list and changed the name from Objects to InstantiatedObjects.

but now i'm getting in the editor all the time out of bound index exception error on the line 32:

if ((mustBeAnObject) && (InstantiatedObjects[i] == null))

ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index) (at <75633565436c42f0a6426b33f0132ade>:0)
SliderManager.SetSlider (System.Int32 x) (at Assets/SliderManager.cs:32)
SliderManager.Update () (at Assets/SliderManager.cs:23)

line 23 is the line inside the Update.

i know what it means the error but not sure how to fix it.

what i'm trying to do is to use the Slider to insatiate objects when sliding the slider to the right and to destroy/remove objects when moving to the left.

it was working fine with the array until i needed to remove items from the array that's why i switched to List

Updated what i tried :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using static UnityEditor.Progress;

[ExecuteAlways]
public class SliderManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider slider;
    public List<GameObject> InstantiatedObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    public GameObject Model;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        SetSlider((int)slider.value);
    }

    protected void SetSlider(int x)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < slider.value; i++)
        {
            bool mustBeAnObject = i < x;

            if (mustBeAnObject)
                InstantiatedObjects.Add(Instantiate(Model));

            // one loop for killing too many items
            while (InstantiatedObjects.Count > slider.value)
            {
                // could as well simply remove the first item if you prefer (0)
                var index = InstantiatedObjects.Count - 1;
                var item = InstantiatedObjects[index];
                InstantiatedObjects.RemoveAt(index);

                if (!Application.isPlaying)
                {
                    DestroyImmediate(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    Destroy(item);
                }
            }

            // one loop for spawning missing items
            while (InstantiatedObjects.Count > slider.value)
            {
                InstantiatedObjects.Add(Instantiate(Model));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this not working good when moving the slider to value 0 back one item left and if moving the slider very fast some items left both in hierarchy and the list.

if i'm trying this code without the lines :

```
bool mustBeAnObject = i < x;
    
                if (mustBeAnObject)
                    InstantiatedObjects.Add(Instantiate(Model));
```

then it's not creating objects at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment you remove an object from the list (`InstantiatedObjects.RemoveAt(0);`) the list shrinks

=> all the later items are shifted down one index

=> all your later indices are **wrong**! Even directly in the next call already for e.g. `DestroyImmediate(InstantiatedObjects[i]);` this already refers to the item **after** the one you just removed!

You could rather do e.g.

```
protected void SetSlider(int x)
{
    // one loop for killing too many items
    while(InstantiatedObjects.Count > slider.value)
    {
        // could as well simply remove the first item if you prefer (0)
        var index = InstantiatedObjects.Count - 1;
        var item = InstantiatedObjects[index];
        InstantiatedObjects.RemoveAt(index);

        if (!Application.isPlaying)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(item);
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(Item);
        }
    }

    // one loop for spawning missing items
    while(InstantiatedObjects.Count < slider.value)
    {
        InstantiatedObjects.Add(Instantiate(Model));
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried that solution but now when the slider is back to value 0 still one item left and if i move the slider very fast some items keep left.  i edited my question with the code i tried with your solution.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi remove that entire `for` loop please ...

Comment: removed it but now this will never work : while (InstantiatedObjects.Count > slider.value) because the InstantiatedObjects.Count length is 0 at the start and the slider value is also 0 and then when i'm moving the slider to the right for example the slider value is 10 the InstantiatedObjects.Count length is still 0.

Comment: @BenziAvrumi well, yes ... but in that case you also do not want to delete any items ... you only want to spawn new ones which will make the list size reach the slider.value

Comment: @BenziAvrumi ah sorry my bad ... the comparison needs to be inverted at the bottom loop of course